# Makefile for Assembly uses implicit rules instead of explicit rules

Tags: assembly, makefile

I have created the following simple Makefile to compile `.s` files into `.o` files using `as` and then link them using `ld`:

```
AS=as
LD=ld

ASFLAGS=-g
LDFLAGS=

targets = rpn cpuid_write cpuid_printf cpuid1 foo decode2 359

all: $(targets)

%: %.o
        $(LD) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.s
        $(AS) $< -o $@ $(ASFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -f *.o  $(targets)
```

When I attempt to compile using this Makefile, say, by typing `$ make rpn`, I receive the following output followed by an error:

```
cc -g    rpn.s   -o rpn
/tmp/ccQab9W.o: In function `_start':
```

...

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: rpn] Error 1
```

It seems the Makefile is defaulting to the implicit rules for compiling a C file rather than my generic rules to compile an Assembly file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the makefile called `Makefile`? What implementation of `make` do you use?

Comment: Is the makefile in the right directory?

Comment: Looks like it's using a built-in rule to go straight from the `.s` to the executable.  I think you need to disable that if you don't want it, check the `Makefile` man page / documentation.

Comment: not your problem related, but `all` should be `.phony` too? Can you try `make -d rpn` or at least `make --debug=i rpn`? And maybe pick up some interesting bits and post here (IIRC, the full output will be huge). Some more interesting options from my `man make`: `-r, --no-builtin-rules` Eliminate use of the built-in implicit rules / `-p, --print-data-base` Print the data base (rules and variable values) that results from reading the makefiles / `--trace`

Comment: @fuz Yes, the makefile is called Makefile and is in the directory with all of the `.s` files.

Comment: @Ped7g Using the `-r` option works great, but @RenaudPacalet has the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably replace your non-terminal match-anything rule:

```
%: %.o
        $(LD) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

by a more specific static pattern rule:

```
$(targets): %: %.o
        $(LD) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

The static pattern rule takes precedence over the `rpn.s -> rpn` implicit rule while the non-terminal match-anything rule does not. The complete explanation is in section [Implicit Rule Search Algorithm section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search) of the GNU make manual. Be prepared to spend some time on it...